# Feed an observable with two more observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs-observables

I have a scenario with 3 webservices, say A, B and C.

A and B can be invoked without arguments. C requires parameters deriving from both A and B. For example:

```
   http.get("A").subscribe(x => console.log(x))
   // prints 'goofy'
   http.get("B").subscribe(y => console.log(y))
   // prints 'mickey'
   http.get("C?param1=goofy&param2=mickey").subscribe(z => console.log(z))
   // prints 'daisy'
```

I wonder how to create a single Observable that does the job, and whose subscription return the result from webservice C.

```
  obs1 = http.get("A")
  obs2 = http.get("B")
  f3 = (x,y => http.get("C?param1="+x+"&param2="+y))
  bigObservable = someconcatenationof(obs1, obs2, f3)
```

and I would like that

```
  bigObservable.subscribe(z => console.log(z))
  // should print "daisy"
```

I suppose that this question can be a little bit generalized: A, B, C do not need to be webservices, they can just be some kind of Observable's, where C's constructor requires results from both A and B.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be one approach:

```js
forkJoin({
  a: http.get("A"),
  b: http.get("B"),
}).pipe(
  mergeMap(({ a, b }) => http.get(`C?param1=${a}&param2=${b}`))
)
```

`forkJoin` will subscribe to all the provided observables at the same time and will emit their last values when all of them complete.